# Named many to many relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

How should I create following model in Rails 3.2? Project can have 1+ owners and 1+ users. Both of them are instances of class Person. I've thought about `has_and_belongs_to_many` but I don't know how to handle two separate collections of Persons for each Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a join model to represent each `has-and-belongs-to-many` relationship, and you would access using `has-many-through` as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

```
class ProjectOwnerLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'Person'
end

class ProjectUserLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'Person'
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_owner_links
  has_many :owners, :through => :project_owner_links
  has_many :project_user_links
  has_many :users, :through => :project_user_links
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_owner_links
  has_many :owned_projects, :through => :project_owner_links, :source => :project
  has_many :project_user_links
  has_many :used_projects, :through => :project_user_links, :source => :project
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define another model `Participation` that holds the type of the relationship, i.e. the role of the user. (Untested) code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

  def with_role(role)
    includes(:participations).where('participation.role = ?', role)
  end

  def owners
    users.with_role('owner')
  end

  def participants
    users.with_role('participant')
  end
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :projects, :through => :participations

  def with_role(role)
    includes(:participations).where('participation.role = ?', role)
  end

  def projects_owned
    projects.with_role('owner')
  end

  def projects_participating_in
    projects.with_role('participant')
  end
end
```

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has an attribute 'role'

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the demo application.

https://github.com/diatmpravin/habtm-demo.git

Please have a look, Let me know if you have any question?